# Google app engine - Python: How to use Namespaces and Ancestors?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, multi-tenant

I'm trying to understand how namespaces and ancestors work in GAE. 
So I made a simple multitenant "ToDo List" application where each tenant is a user. So I set the namespaces in **appengine_config.py** like so:

```
def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
    name = users.GetCurrentUser().user_id()
return name
```

And then in my **main.py** I manage the views like so:

```
#Make tasks with strong consistency by giving them a parent
DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR = ndb.Key('Agenda', 'default_agenda')


class TasksList(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    namespace = namespace_manager.get_namespace()
    tasks_query = Task.query(ancestor=DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR)
    tasks = tasks_query.fetch(10, use_cache=False)
    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'namespace': namespace,
    }
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/tasks_list.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(context))

def post(self):
    name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('name'))
    task = Task(parent=DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR)
    task.name = name
    task.put()
    self.redirect('/tasks_list')
```

...And that gave a leaking data:

1. I logged in as userA, created a task, then logged out and logged in again as a different     user (userB), and I could see that task from userA.
   I confirmed from the admin panel that the task entities are from different namespaces and that the ancestor is also different "since it includes the namespace?".
2. I also turned caching off by using `.fetch(10, use_cache=False)`. But the problem was still there. So it was not a caching issue.
3. So finally I make the parent just before `.query()` and `.put()` and it did work! Like so:
   `DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR = ndb.Key('Agenda', 'default_agenda')
   tasks_query = Task.query(ancestor=DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR)`

But now I have questions...

1. Why it worked? Since those task entities don't share the same namespace, how could I query data from another namespace? Even if I query for an ancestor from another namespace by mistake should I get the data?
2. Is *DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR* from **namespaceA** the same ancestor as *DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR* from the **namespaceB**, or are they two completely different ancestors?
3. Do namespaces really compartmentalize data in the datastore or is that not the case?
4. If ancestors play that much of a big role even in namespaces, should I still use namespaces or ancestors to compartmentalize data in a multitenant application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem was defining the `DEFAULT_TASKS_ANCESTOR` constant outside of the requests. In that case, datastore used the default namespace to create this key. So by querying with that ancestor key, you used the same namespace.

From Google's datastore [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Python_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore):

> By default, the datastore uses the current namespace setting in the namespace manager for datastore requests. The API applies this current namespace to Key or Query objects when they are created. Therefore, you need to be careful if an application stores Key or Query objects in serialized forms, since the namespace is preserved in those serializations.

As you have found out, it worked when you defined the ancestor key inside the requests. You can set the namespace for a particular query in the constructor call (i.e. `ndb.Query(namespace='1234')`), so you can query entities from a different namespace.

For your other questions:

2. These are in my understanding different keys, since they include different namespaces.
3. To make a hard compartmentalization, you could check on the server side whether the namespace used for a query is equal to the userID of the current user.
4. It really depends on the overall structure of the application. IMHO, ancestor keys are more relevant with regard to strong consistency. Think of the situation where a user might have several todo-lists. He should be able to see them all, but strong consistency may only be required at the list level.